# Adblock blocker blocking urllib.request.urlopen()

Tags: python, web-scraping, adblock

I am using Python to scrape newspaper sites and collect the actual story in text after removing various HTML tags etc.

My simple code is as follows

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#targetURL = 'http://indianexpress.com/article/india/mamata-banerjee-army-deployment-nh-2-in-west-bengal-military-coup-4405871'
targetURL = "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Congress-Twitter-hacking-Police-form-cyber-team-launch-probe/articleshow/55737598.cms"
#targetURL = 'http://www.telegraphindia.com/1161201/jsp/nation/story_122343.jsp#.WEDzfXV948o'

with urllib.request.urlopen(targetURL) as url:
    html = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

for el in soup.find_all("p"):
    print (el.text)
```

when I am accessing the indianexpress.com URL or the telegraphindia.com URL, the code is working just fine and I am getting the story, by and large without junk, in pure text form.

however the timesofindia.com site has an adblock blocker and in this case, the output is as follows :

```
We have noticed that you have an ad blocker enabled which restricts ads served on the site.
Please disable to continue reading.
```

How can I get bypass this Adblock blocker and retrieve the page? Will be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual content you're trying to extract isn't inside of `<p>` tags. However, the ad blocker warning is inside such tags. This text is always part of the HTML document but only made visible to users if ads fail to load.

Try extracting the contents of the `<arttextxml>` tag instead.